# Programs and features - columns missing after restart

Tags: windows-10, add-and-remove-programs

Once I've enabled column `Location` after restart the column is disabled.
More then that, few other columns are now disabled and apps are listed in reverse order.

I guess those setting is saved somewhere in registry, but I didn't find it.

Where is saved the appwiz.cpl layout?
How to prevent those unwanted changes?

I'm on Win 10 19045.3448.

Comment: Try making adding the column while logged on in Administrator account.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm member of group `Administrator`.
If I change the layout and keep `Localtion` disabled everything is just fine.